# Issues with breaking loops and static variables in Android Studio Java code

Tags: java, loops, android-studio, static, break

I run into two problems writing java code in android studio.

here is my code:

```
static String price, title;


private void initData() {
        adList = new ArrayList<>();
        int i=0;
        outerloop:
        /*while(true)*/for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
            UserRef.child(String.valueOf(i)).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
                        if(snapshot.exists()){
                            String userid = task.getResult().getValue().toString();
                            interloop:
                            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                                AdvertisementsRef.child(userid).child(String.valueOf(j)).child("advertisement_price").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
                                            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                                price = task.getResult().getValue().toString();
                                            }else{
                                                //break interloop;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                AdvertisementsRef.child(userid).child(String.valueOf(j)).child("title").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                                        title = task.getResult().getValue().toString();
                                    }
                                });
                                adList.add(new MainModel(price, title, R.drawable.google));
                            }
                        }else{
                            //break outerloop;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            i++;
        }
    }
```

I tried to break an outerloop and interloop with labels but this is not working, and i don't have any idea how to fix it. Also, static variables aren't working because when i leave the method, those act like a normal declared variable (there is no value). Can anyone help?

PS: there is a lot of other code provided in this, try to focus just on the problems of breaking and global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You're *break intraloop* statement is within a different scope.

The *[Task#addOnCompleteListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/OnCompleteListener)* method is using an *[anonymous inner-class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)* as it's first argument.

```java
AdvertisementsRef.child(userid).child(String.valueOf(j)).child("advertisement_price").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                price = task.getResult().getValue().toString();
            }else{
                //break interloop;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a concise example.

```java
label: for (String string : strings) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            break label;
        }
    });
}
```

The new scope starts at the argument's code-block.